# Checkbox toggle in react

Tags: css, reactjs

Here in my app the function 'todoCompleted' is invoked when list item or checkbox is clicked. When i click the checkbox the code is not running correctly.The function is used for both li element and checkbox field.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

  

          constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
        todo:[]
      };
    };

    entertodo(keypress){
      var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
      if( keypress.charCode == 13 )

      {
        this.setState({
          todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false})

        });
        this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
      };
    };
    todo(todo,i){
      return (
        <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
          <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}>
            <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
            <div key={todo.id}  className="item">
              {todo.Value}
              <div className="Button">
              <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    };

    remove(i){
      this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
      this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
    };
    todoCompleted(i){
       var todo=this.state.todo;
       {
         todo[i].checked =true;
         this.setState({
           todo:this.state.todo
         });
       }
     };
    allCompleted=()=>{
      var todo = this.state.todo;
      var _this = this
      todo.forEach(function(item) {
       item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
       item.checked = !_this.state.finished
   })
   this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
    };

      render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
            <div className="lines"></div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
                <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">x</span>
              </div>
              <div className="mainapp">
                <ul>
                {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
      

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
    .line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `todoCompleted` method is invoked 2 times when you click on the `input` element. It is also bound 3 times for each `li` element: on `li`, on `input`, and on `button` click. As a quick fix, you could reformat the structure of your `li` element in the following way:

Demo here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/bwmwqz

```
      <li className={text.Decor}>
        <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}>
          <input type="checkbox"
                 className="option-input checkbox"
                 checked={text.checked} />
          <div key={text.id}
               className="item">
            {text.Value}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button"
                className="destroy"
                onClick={this.remove.bind(this,i)}>
          X
        </button>
      </li>
```

Please note

- the new div structure,
- `i` is now passed to the `remove` method, and also that
- the `todoCompleted` method is **bound only once**. For performance reasons, you should avoid using bind or arrow functions when rendering JSX. This is because a copy of the event handling function is created for every instance generated by the map() function. This is explained here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Also you have been mutating the state:

```
  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
```

Instaed of the above you can:

```
  remove(i){
    this.setState({
      todo: [
        ...this.state.todo.slice(0, i),
        ...this.state.todo.slice(i + 1)
      ]
    });
  };
```

Comment: I changed the code slightly. Instead of using className in todoCompleted, i made changes in list element, but stuck in middle and not finding way to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `this.todoCompleted` fired twice here (simplified your html):

```
<li onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}>
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)} checked={text.checked} />
</li>
```

First, the one on `li` fired. It sets checkbox to correct state like it should. But then, the one on actual checkbox fired! And set todo back to the unchecked state. So it looks like it' not working :)

You could easily see it if you move checkbox out of `li` element like i do here: http://www.webpackbin.com/Nk9NTh0RZ

Answer (score 0):

How Toggle Multiple Checkbox in Reactjs

```
const [cardChacked, setcardChacked] = useState(false);

const onInput = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    setInput({ CompanyInput: value });

    setCheckedItems(false);
  };

 <input
    onChange={onInput}
    className={
        checkedItems === "noti_6" &&
        cardChacked === true &&
        CompanyInput !== ""
            ? "label-active"
            : ""
    }
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).